# Request Timed out when trying to add iOS device to the portal

Tags: ios, xcode

I added my iPad device to the Apple Developer website by entering it's description and UDID.

Within the Xcode organizer, I attempt to add my device to the portal.  I have hooked up a proper provisioning portal to it and all. Yet, the request times out every single time after I enter my proper Apple ID and password.

[image: Error]

How do I fix this?

Also, if it helps: I get the same error when I go to Editor < Refresh from Developer Portal

Comment: It may have something to do with the WWDC - not entirely sure.

Comment: This is happening to me as well.  Timing out on Adding to Portal and Refreshing.

Comment: It's WWDC again, and it's happening again.

Comment: Possibly something todo with recent Apple servers hack, Apple is slowly restoring servers.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Here is what you're after...

Check the following status page -
https://developer.apple.com/support/system-status/

If the "Xcode Automatic Configuration" is grayed out, that means the service is offline, and Xcode will surely time out on all developer portal related activities.

If "Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles" service is online, then Xcode will still time out, but you can access the web developer portal, manually add a device (Identifier), modify / update certificates and download them, and manually add them to your Xcode, and continue with your development / provisioning / ad-hoc distribution.

Hope this helps!

Comment: My team provisioning profile became invalid (because I had to renew my developer certificate).  It is apparently "managed by Xcode", but I assume that won't happen until "Xcode Automatic Configuration" comes back online?

Comment: @brainjam Today I had to clean up some keys and certificates. Basically I did remove a bit too much, but the Team Provisioning Profile was created for me in the end. But that was only after I did restore the keys and certificates in my keychain. Can you check your keychain for a valid iphone developer certificate?

I can also confirm that creating with Xcode is not possible for now, but online works just fine.

Comment: That page is perhaps not up to date. I am getting timeouts right now and the page says everything is up.

Answer (score 10):

I had this same problem. Here's how I got around it:
Login to developer.apple.com and go to the provisioning profiles section:

https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/profile/profileList.action

First you have to manually add your device in the Devices section. You can get your UDID from iTunes by selecting the device and then clicking on the identifier.

Now you can manually generate a new provisioning profile that includes this device.
Go down to "Provisioning Profiles" section. Click the "+", then "iOS App Development" - Continue. Then AppID "iOS Wildcard" - Continue. Then your developer certificate in the checkbox - Continue. Now you should see your new device in the devices section. Add all of these devices, and download the new certificate. Once you have imported this new certificate into your Organizer, it should work (well, it did for me).

Let me know if this doesn't work for you for some reason and I can try to help by comparing what's happening with mine.

Comment: I wish there was some other way to add device into "team provisioning profile"

Comment: If my team provisioning profile is invalid, I guess Xcode won't fix it until Apple's servers come back up?

Answer (score 1):

Just hooked up a new iPhone and trying to deploy my apps on it. No joy so far. Playing around with the profiles & provisions on the website is to no avail, since the development one is "managed by Xcode". Which currently serves up nothing more useful than a timeout.

Answer (score 1):

I just got a call from Apple Developer Relations about the WWDC registrations and they told me about technical issues they have been having. Perhaps it is a wider issue?