# Xcode organiser on mac keep returning request timed out

Tags: xcode

I am trying to refresh my provisioning profiles on the Xcode organizer.
all I get is a "request timed out" after a while.

I tried removing other profiles but it doesn't work.

The only thing that is different today than when it worked before is that I have changes my app ID password but I do not have any login problems.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Request Timed out when trying to add iOS device to the portal](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16225754/request-timed-out-when-trying-to-add-ios-device-to-the-portal)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and with this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17954559/1718203) confirmed that apple was the problem.