# Xcode struck in validation process?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, xcode6.3

I use Xcode 6.3 , and I am trying to Validate and then submit an app to the apple store . I press Validate but its being validate but its stuck in that point , and then after long time waiting its rejected for "time out".What is the problem here please guide me any one.for better understanding i am adding my screen shots.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B14zCKcRh39Ad2JUbXI5MU01YXM/view?usp=sharing
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B14zCKcRh39AZWhBWlp4SDFWcU0/view?usp=sharing

Comment: It happened with me.. Tried after sometime & it worked.. So will suggest you the same, Try after some time...

Comment: If your concern is just to submit app on app store. you can submit your app using application loader. I think it will work for you to submit app on app store

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19512877/xcode-5-hangs-with-a-timeout-error-when-validating-uploading-a-ready-to-be-uplo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

please check the following link

[Request Timed out when trying to add iOS device to the portal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16225754/request-timed-out-when-trying-to-add-ios-device-to-the-portal/17954559#17954559)

Also i can suggest you, better upload app by using application loader.
for making ipa file, follow the following steps!

Open your project using xCode

Go to build setting and select distribution profile

Clean project

Select "iOS device" option for particular Project Scheme

Build project

Go to Project Navigator

Open "Products" group

You can find ".app" file of your project.

Right click on ".app" file and select "Show in Finder" option

In Finder, Right click on ".app" and compress the file.

Now you have "urappname.app.zip" file, move it somewhere else for future use.

Using Application Loader, how to do process ipa to itunesconnect, you can follow steps using below reference link

http://jaym2503.blogspot.in/2012/09/how-to-upload-binaryipa-to-app-store.html

it may be help you! all the best!!